# c-mode inconsistent indentation (sometimes tabs, sometimes spaces)

Tags: indentation, c-mode

I have the following line in my .emacs file:

`(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`

but sometimes my indents still come through as tabs rather than spaces in c-mode. It is inconsistent; roughly 70% of my c-mode indents are made up of spaces and the rest of them are tabs. I haven't seen this issue in any other major mode.

Here is the only c-mode hook I have specified in my .emacs file:

```c
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook (lambda () (setq comment-start "//"
                                        comment-end "")))
```

I'm not certain, but I think the tabs rather than spaces might happen only when auto-indenting. Does anyone have any ideas why this might be the case?

I'm on Emacs 29.1, but also see the behavior on Emacas 28.3 (I haven't tried other versions).

Comment: Check that `indent-tabs-mode` really has value `nil` in the buffers where you see creation of indentation with TAB chars. It's `Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.` And it can be a file-local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you may have messed up the indentation while using an old version of your config that did not set `indent-tabs-mode` properly. Try running `C-x h TAB` to fix the indentation of the whole buffer and see if tabs appear again.

Secondly, make sure your `c-default-style` does not set the value of `indent-tabs-mode`, for example the "linux" one sets it to `t`.

Finally, you can create your own C style and use it by either setting it as the default for `c-default-style` or by calling `c-set-style` in the `c-mode-hook`.

If you want to make it simpler (I do not claim that it will work though), you can set the indentation style in each buffer individually, for example by augmenting your hook :

```lisp
(defun my-c-setup ()
  "Custom setup for C."
  (interactive)
  (setq-local comment-start "//"
              comment-end ""
              indent-tabs-mode nil))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-setup)
```

Comment: Thanks! The issue was the c-default-style